# JAVA and Flex via chrome error 2032. response body is too large

Tags: java, json, apache-flex, google-chrome, response

I have an application i made using java and flex, that communicate with json. I have tested it many times and it all work well, but after some test it just stop working.

in the debug process I notice that when i send httpservice request to my server via chrome I'm getting the HttpService post error 2032.

I tried to look up for this problem and came across this:
http://old.nabble.com/HttpService-post-error-2032:iostream-error-td16533829.html

they say there that this error may occurs when the response body is too large.

I made the response size smaller and it worked fine.

this problem occurs only via chrome.

in the Network Monitor view in Flex Builder i see the response with an error in the tree view, but when i change to raw view, i see the response body json as a expected and the header is HTTP/1.1 200 OK. but still the HTTPService invoke the fault function, not the result.

the response size over 9Kb invoke the error. less than that is working fine.

I'm running a Java server Tomcat v7.0 on windows 7 64 bit, and chrome 17.0.963.78 m.

this is the error i get:

[RPC Fault faultString="HTTP request error" faultCode="Server.Error.Request" faultDetail="Error: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032"]. URL: http://localhost:8080/MBankServer/GetClientManifest"]

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTPS request returning 2032 Stream Error only for Android with Flex 4.6 Mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978689/https-request-returning-2032-stream-error-only-for-android-with-flex-4-6-mobile)