# Why am I suddenly getting stream error while using URLLoader?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I've been working on an android app project for an year and I implemented this feature in the very beginning. The app is a expense/savings management app, and it has a feature that converts the currencies in the background if user is currently in a different country. I am using geonames API to find out the name of the country. Here is the relevant code:

```
countryURLRequest = new URLRequest('http://api.geonames.org/findNearby?lat='+latitudes+'&lng='+longitudes+'&username=fatninja');
countryURLLoader = new URLLoader();

countryURLLoader.load(countryURLRequest);
```

Today, when I sent lat and lng values from the simulator I got the said stream error at this line:

```
countryURLLoader = new URLLoader();
```

What's weird is that this feature has been working fine since the beginning. I thought it might have been a bug in the code so I ran the project from backup (from 3 months ago), it's giving the same error. I know for a fact that it was working 3 months ago. What could be the problem?

Comment: What is the complete error message you're seeing? Does it occur during compilation or at runtime?

Comment: Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://api.geonames.org/findNearby?lat=12.21354&lng=6.432163&username=fatninja
 at TodayPopup/onGeoUpdated()[F:\(address-removed)\TodayPopup.as:164]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is indicating that you're running into a problem while fetching the data. Nothing's wrong with your code. It might be that your network configuration has changed, and that's preventing access to the web service.

This is further supported by the fact that you're facing the same problem with your previously working code.

There are two things you should do.

1. Add an IO error event handler and a HTTP status event handler.

   var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
   loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loader_ioErrorHandler); // Note that the listener is added to the contentLoaderInfo object
   loader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, loader_httpStatusHandler);
   loader.load(new URLRequest("www.example.com"));

   function loader_ioErrorHandler(e:IOErrorEvent):void
   {
       // Handle the error
       trace(e.text);
   }

   function loader_httpStatusHandler(e:HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS):void
   {
       trace(e.status);
   }

Add labels to notify the user about the error in the IO error handler, and maybe a button to retry the request.

2. Increase the duration of the timeout by using the requestTimeout property of the HTTPService instance.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for the answer. When I changed the AIR SDK version from 22.0 to 20.0, it worked just like it did before. Could it be a bug in the SDK?

Comment: I do see an old bug report about a similar problem. But that's been reported fixed in AIR SDK 2.5. I don't think they'd have a regression so far down the line.

Have you checked the suggestions made by Dominic at http://stackoverflow.com/a/9986938/229367? It might happen that the newer SDK has a different set of default permissions, or might have changed the way permissions are declared.